# What is the best way to print this matrix without a for loop

Tags: python

We have a matrix like this:

```
[[a1,a2,a3],[a4,a5,a6],[a7,a8,a9]]
```

What is the best way to print that list on separate lines?

I don't want to print it using a loop:

```
for row in matrix:
    print row
```

I want to know if there is an internal procedure to do that.

Desired output:

```
[a1, a2, a3]
[a4, a5, a6]
[a7, a8, a9]
```

Comment: Can you show us the desired output you want?

Comment: @Aamir Adnan it doesn't matter i only wanted it on separated lines.

Comment: What do you mean by "best way to print each row in separate line"?

Comment: this already prints each row in a newline.. yeah the rephrasing helped! and why don;t you want to use a for loop, what do you have in mind?

Comment: @iKlsR I wan't to use somthing like "\n".join

Comment: why would you want to do that, i suggest going with the for loop, don't try to complicate simple tasks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A minimalist approach:

```
In [1]: l=[['a1','a2','a3'],['a4','a5','a6'],['a7','a8','a9']]

In [2]: from __future__ import print_function

In [3]: print(*l,sep='\n')
['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
['a4', 'a5', 'a6']
['a7', 'a8', 'a9']
```

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way to do so without using a for loop as you asked is

```
print matrix[0], "\n", matrix[1], "\n", matrix[2]
```

*I urge you to make use of loops as they are a useful thing, while this example is relatively simple, imagine a case like this with hundreds of rows,, would you manually type out each line?*

Answer (score 2):

not using for loop will make the code messy

```
i=0
while i <len(m):
    print m[i]
    i = i+1
```

try this

Comment: if large matrix assign len(m) to a variable and change limiting condition of while loop to i<variable cause calling len function every time will decrease the efficiency

Answer (score 0):

```
    print [m1 for m1 in m]
```

yields:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: That is the exact same thing the OP has now. Why write it up again?